# Tkinter window does not load completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to have a progress window which shows the progress, alongside having tasks happening in the background. Everything works as expected, except the window partially loads on to the screen (how much of it does depends on every run). Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
def loading(): #Displays loading progress while setting up the exam
    global load, progress      
    load = Toplevel()
    load.title("Loading")
    load.attributes('-topmost', True)
    load.overrideredirect(True)
    lab = Label(load, text = ("Preparing Your Exam, Please Wait!\nPlease DO NOT Open any Other Window.\n"
                              +"Doing so may lead to immidiate Termination."))
    lab.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)
    progress=Progressbar(load,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=200,mode='determinate')
    progress.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)
    log = Label(load, image = logo)
    log.image = logo
    log.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 2, padx = 20, pady = 20)
    w_req, h_req = load.winfo_width(), load.winfo_height()
    w_form = load.winfo_rootx() - load.winfo_x()
    w = w_req + w_form*2
    h = h_req + (load.winfo_rooty() - load.winfo_y()) + w_form
    x = (load.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (w // 2)
    y = (load.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (h // 2)
    load.geometry(f'{w_req}x{h_req}+{x}+{y}')
```

Here's what happens after calling `loading`:

```
loading()
conv_th = Thread(target = Convert).start()
```

The `Convert` function converts and processes images, I'm not sharing that because it might not be relevant.

I far as I think, it might be because it is not getting enough time to load completely, but I couldn't really figure out what could be causing the program to behave this way. Any help will be appreciated!

**Update:** This behavior is seen even if `conv_th = Thread(target = Convert).start()` is omitted, implying that there could be a problem within the `loading()` function.

Comment: Try using an `after` call to start the processing after 1 second so the load has time to complete.

Comment: @Mike67 Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work, I tried `initial.after(1000, conv_th.start)` but the same results. I have also tried calling the `Thread` from within the `loading` function at the end, but no difference.

Comment: Unless your `Convert()` function does some I/O or otherwise releases the GIL frequently enough (i.e. it's compute-bound), it may be interferring with tkinter's `mainloop()`. You might be able to mitigate that by calling the universal widget method [`w.update_idletasks()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) — which can (also) be scheduled via the `after()` method.

Comment: @martineau Thank you for the quick reply, I will try that out, but I noticed something now, the window opens partially even if I don't call the convert. Is there a problem within the `loading()` function?

Comment: is this `conv_th = Thread(target = Convert).start()` implemented to a button, because if it is then you will have to remove the `()` from `start()` or itll start automatically

Comment: @CoolCloud It is not, and I want it to start automatically after the loading window shows up. Please check the update that that I have specified, the issue seems to be independent of this command.

Comment: No its fine, i just pointed out a potential mistake out there. i havent used progressbars before with tkinter

Comment: Likely unrelated to display problem…but `conv_th = Thread(target = Convert).start()` is incorrect in the sense that a `Thread`'s`start()` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: @martineau I realized that, thanks for pointing out, I didn't need the return for anything anyway. Have you figured out what might be causing the display problem? Please let me know if you require any other information for the same.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up solving the problem myself. I'm telling the reason that I think is most probable, please correct me if the reason that I give is incorrect or there is another solution for this.

This part of the code,

```py
w_req, h_req = load.winfo_width(), load.winfo_height()
w_form = load.winfo_rootx() - load.winfo_x()
w = w_req + w_form*2
h = h_req + (load.winfo_rooty() - load.winfo_y()) + w_form
x = (load.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (w // 2)
y = (load.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (h // 2)
```

was being executed too early, before the window could actually load itself up completely, and hence whatever amount of it got loaded before this, was taken as the dimensions and then the values were set.

Adding the command `load.update_idletasks()` before the above part of the code resolved the problem. Thanks @martineau, your comment was really helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: You're welcome…glad to hear one of my comments proved to be helpful.